# Sed to replace string of 10 characters with 'XXXX '

Tags: text-processing

I have file which looks like

```
ACCINTCCADVANCESC
ACCINTCCADVANCESE
ACCINTCCADVANCESW
```

I want to replace `INTCCADVAN` with `XXXX␣␣␣␣␣␣`, the `␣`s are spaces.
Specifically I want to replace a column with more than 150 characters with xxxx and white spaces till the end of 150 characters.

Comment: How should that work with the string to replace in the middle of the words? Can you add a sample of what the output should look like?

Comment: This is a fixed length file without any delimiters, the output should look like 
ACCXXXX      CESC
ACCXXXX      CESE
ACCXXXX      CESW

Comment: please [edit] your question to include that, the comments have really limited formatting options so don't really work well for stuff like this

Comment: I have tided your question. However I can't work it out. It gives an example, then says (and I paraphrase this), specifically it should do something different to the example (I just can't work out what this different thing is).

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and `printf`:

```
$ sed "s/INTCCADVAN/$(printf '%-10s' XXXX)/" file
ACCXXXX      CESC
ACCXXXX      CESE
ACCXXXX      CESW
```

The output by `printf` is 10 characters long and `XXXX` is left aligned using the `-` formatting option.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I am trying to enhance the code, i want to replace the string starting at 500th position on a file and the length is 160 characters. Basically i want to replace the string that starts from 500th position till the position 660.  i have tried this "s/^\(.\{500\}\).\{160\}/\1XXXXX/" . However this just replaces the string with XXXXX but without any spaces till the end.  thanks in advance

Comment: Do it like as this: `$ sed -Ee "s/((.{50}){10}).{160}/\1$(printf "%-160s" XXXX)/"` there are limits on the numbers in regex, so to workaround them we need to break it up.

Comment: Thanks, it works.